# Localhost No 'Access-Control-Allow Error on Live site

Tags: .htaccess, localhost, access-control

I'm getting this error on my live site (hosted on GoDaddy) when I'm trying to make a http get call to an API.

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost' that is not equal to the supplied origin.
```

Why does it think the header has a localhost value when I'm not even running this on my local server? The weird thing is that it happens on and off (sometimes it's able to call the API and get the data without the error, other times, it's not and gives that error.

Comment: I used this code `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in my `php` file, and it's fixed. Hope this help you!

Comment: @MrNeo which php file did you put that in?

Comment: I have a Javscript file that makes the get call to the server. I'm not sure if it's a server side or client side issue.

Comment: I had got this issue before and I add this code into all php file on server which communicate with client side.